# struct que armazena número de linhas e colunas de matriz e de um vetor

Tags: c, loop, matriz, struct, for

Usei uma `struct` para armazenar o número de linhas (m) e colunas (n) da matriz e uma outra pra armazenar número de colunas do vetor (n). Faço o produto de duas matrizes na função `prod()` e o produto de uma matriz com um vetor na função `solve()`, porém a saída está sendo sempre 0. Quero que na saída apareça o vetor gerado do produto da matriz pelo vetor. Não sei como mudar o código para que ele faça o que eu quero, creio que o erro esteja no terceiro `for` que armazena os valores calculados. Eu acho que o erro é aqui, no terceiro `for` da função `prod`:

```
C.p_data[iA.n+j] = C.p_data[iA.n+j]+(A.p_data[i*A.m+k]B.p_data[kB.n+j]);
```

mas não sei como mudar os índices pra armazenar corretamente o valor calculado.

Segue o código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// define tipo matriz com campos linha, coluna e ponteiro
typedef struct{
  int m;
  int n;
  double *p_data;
}matriz_t;

// define tipo vetor, uma struct com campos coluna e ponteiro 
typedef struct{
  int n;
  double *p_data;
}vetor_t;

//prototipo das fucncoes
matriz_t le_matriz();
vetor_t le_vetor();
matriz_t prod(matriz_t A,matriz_t B);
vetor_t solve(matriz_t C,vetor_t a);
void mostra_vetor(vetor_t b);

int main(){
  matriz_t A,B,C;
  vetor_t a,b;
  A = le_matriz();
  B = le_matriz();
  a = le_vetor();
  C = prod(A,B);
  b = solve(C,a);
  mostra_vetor(b);
  return 0;
}

matriz_t le_matriz(){
  matriz_t A;
  int i,j;

  printf("tam M1");

  // armazena n de linhas e de colunas da matriz
  scanf("%d",&A.m);
  scanf("%d",&A.n);

  printf("\n");

  A.p_data = malloc(A.m*A.n*sizeof(double));

  printf("elem m1:\n");  

  // armazena elementos matriz 
  for(i=0;i<A.m;i++){
     for(j=0;j<A.n;j++){
        scanf("%lf", &A.p_data[i*A.n+j]);
     }
  }

  printf("\n");

  return A; 
}

vetor_t le_vetor(){
  vetor_t a;
  int i;

  printf("tam v1\n");

  // armazena tamanho vetor 
  scanf("%d",&a.n);

  a.p_data = malloc(a.n*sizeof(double));

  printf("\n");
  printf("elemv1:\n");

  // armazena elementos do vetor
  for(i=0;i<a.n;i++){
     scanf("%lf",&a.p_data[i*a.n]);
  }

  printf("\n");

  return a;
}

matriz_t prod(matriz_t A, matriz_t B){
  matriz_t C;
  int i,j,k;

  C.p_data = malloc(A.m*B.n*sizeof(double));

  // condicao para o produto matriz matriz
  if(A.n == B.m){
    // percorre coluna matriz A
    for(i=0;i<A.n;i++){
       // percorre linha matriz B
       for(j=0;j<B.m;j++){
         // inicializa terceira matriz com 0
     C.p_data[i*A.n+j] =0;
          // calcula e armazena o resultado numa 3 matriz
          for(k=0;k<B.n;k++){
             C.p_data[i*A.n+j] = C.p_data[i*A.n+j]+(A.p_data[i*A.m+k]*B.p_data[k*B.n+j]); 
          }
       }
    }

    return C;
  }
}

vetor_t solve(matriz_t C, vetor_t a){
  vetor_t b;
  int i,j,k;

  b.p_data = malloc(C.m*a.n*sizeof(double));

  // condicao do produto matriz vetor
  if(C.m == a.n){
   // percorre linha matriz
   for(i=0;i<C.m;i++){
     // percorre coluna vetor
     for(j=0;j<a.n;j++){
       // terceira matriz para receber os valores calculados
       b.p_data[i*C.n+k] = 0;
        for(k=0;k<a.n;k++){
           b.p_data[i] = b.p_data[i]+(C.p_data[i*C.n+k]*a.p_data[k*a.n+j]);
        }
     }
   }

   return b;
  }
}

void mostra_vetor(vetor_t b){
  int i;

  // mostra valores do vetor
  for(i=0;i<b.n;i++){
     printf("%lf\n",b.p_data[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/8lbncD

Comment: Por favor, faça o [tour] para entender o básico do funcionamento do site. Nele você encontrará dicas primárias de formatação da sua pergunta. O [pt.so] utiliza o formato Markdown, mas se desconhece, você aprenderá o básico no tour.